# How to choose the proper value of resistors for current dividers

Tags: current, resistors, current-divider

Edit: The original version of this question is malformed. There is an edit further down below with an updated explanation of the issue I'm trying to solve.

In a simple current divider, I know the ratio of the parallel resistors determines the current flowing through each parallel section of the circuit, however, I don't know which resistance fits best on a given circuit.

Given a 5V/5A dc power supply, a ratio of 2/3 would mean that one circuit would get 2A and the other would get 3, but that would be true both with a 2Ω and 3Ω resistor and a 2kΩ and 3kΩ resistor.

[image: circuit order of 1 ohm resistance]

[image: circuit order of 1000 ohm resistance]

How is the proper resistance determined?

### Edit

I see my misunderstanding. I made this question because I am working on a project where I have two loads that I have to connect in parallel, and each of them require different currents to go through them. I do not know their resistance, and it can probably vary, given that they are a microcontroller and an LCD.

The load of the screen requires a power supply of 5V and at most 2A. The load of the microcontroller requires a 5V power supply capable of reaching, but not limited to, 3A.

The problem is that I need to power both of these loads from the same source, and since one of them requires a higher load than what the other can take, I am worried I am going to damage the smaller load (the screen). I thought of using a current divider for this, but now it doesn't seem like the best idea. After searching some more I think a current limiter will do a better job at protecting the screen, but I am still unsure on how to go about this. This seems like should be on a different question though, so I'll write a new one. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Do the calculations again for a 2 kΩ and 3 kΩ resistor - are you sure that 5 V will give the currents you suggest? Something is wrong.

Comment: Power supplies generally are either constant voltage with current limit or constant current with voltage limit. Your example of a power supply is unrealistic. In the latter case with kilo-ohm resistors, there would be 6000 volts over the resistors. Did you really mean a 6 kilovolt 5A capable 30 kilowatt supply? That's enough to power a small home.

Comment: Ciro, I think a misunderstanding is that a power supply is ***both*** \$5\:\text{V}\$ ***and*** \$5\:\text{A}\$ at the same time. A power supply cannot be set to both those things. You get to set one, or the other, leaving the remaining to be a `compliance`. But not both. A power supply rated at \$5\:\text{A}\$ doesn't mean it forces that amount. It just says that it can supply that much, if required of it. It's a *compliance* spec.

Comment: By putting a 5A current source in series with the 5V voltage source, you're *forcing* 5A to flow through your circuit. You'll find that you now have 6kV across your resistors. A "5V/5A dc supply" usually *allows up to* 5A, it is not a current source, it's a voltage source with a limit.

Comment: To address the main part of your question - in "real life" you wouldn't typically implement a current divider in isolation like that for no reason. You need to consider *why* you're implementing a current divider and for what purpose these divided current will be used. That's what will determine (to at least one order of magnitude) what range of resistances you'll choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a **constant voltage source** you could use any combination of resistors where their ratio is 2 to 3, for example you could use 40\$\Omega\$ and 90\$\Omega\$, but each different pair of values will give you different currents. They don't take the power supply current rating and divide it, rather the current in each will be the supply voltage divided by that resistance.

In your circuits you have 2\$\Omega\$ and 3\$\Omega\$ in one, that will give not give you 3 A and 2 A, it will give you
$$
\frac{5 V}{2\Omega} = 2.5 A
$$
and
$$
\frac{5 V}{3\Omega} = 1.667 A
$$
for a total of 4.167 A

The second circuit with the values in kilohms will give you the same values except in milliamps instead of amps.

So the current you're dividing isn't the supply max current, it's the current the two resistors in parallel would draw.

2\$\Omega\$  in parallel with 3\$\Omega\$ is
$$
\frac{2\Omega \times 3\Omega}{2\Omega + 3\Omega} = 1.2\Omega
$$

and the total current would be
$$
\frac{5 V}{1.2\Omega} = 4.167 A
$$
so that matches what we got by adding the two currents.

For a **constant current source** the currents would divide the constant current according to their ratios, but the voltage would adjust to keep the total current at a given value.

Let's say you had a 5 A constant current supply, and used 2\$\Omega\$ and 3\$\Omega\$  resistors, the currents would be 3 A and 2 A, but the supply would adjust its voltage to be 6 V, and the calculations would be
$$
\frac{6 V}{2\Omega} = 3 A
$$
and
$$
\frac{6 V}{3\Omega} = 2 A
$$

and for the 2k\$\Omega\$ and 3k\$\Omega\$  resistors the currents would be the same, but the supply would need to output 6000 V.
$$
\frac{6000 V}{2k\Omega} = 3 A
$$
and
$$
\frac{6000 V}{3k\Omega} = 2 A
$$

Which might be a problem, because just as a constant voltage supply has a current limit, a constant current supply has a voltage limit, they will source a given current as long as the load resistance times that current doesn't exceed the voltage limit.

For example, a 5 A CCS with a compliance voltage of 30 V would only source 5 A into a resistance if it is less than or equal to
$$
\frac{30 V}{5 A} = 6\Omega
$$

Answer (score 0):

If both loads are designed to operate from 5 volts, they will each draw whatever current they require from your 5 volt supply.  There is no need for you to try to control the individual currents.

Comment: Is an overload not possible if the supply can provide a current higher than the component can take? I don't know if I can trust the component itself to have its own current overload protection, as it won't be cheap to replace it if it breaks

Comment: It is normal, even desirable, that a power supply can deliver a higher current than the load requires.  Consider the AC wiring in your home: a normal outlet can deliver 15 amps (actually,much more...) but you can plug in a phone charger drawing a few mA or a heater drawing 12 amp without concern.  Your car battery can deliver a few hundred amps to the starting motor, while also delivering a few mA to LED lights in the dash.  If a device draws more current than the designer intended, it is already broken.