# Protecting parallel loads

Tags: power-supply, circuit-protection, current-limiting

I have a project that has two separate sections that must be powered from the same power source. I do not know the resistance of said loads, but I know the power supply that each of them on their own would need. I apologize in advance for any ignorant mistakes you find in this question, I'm a software guy and I haven't done much beyond following Arduino schematics.

The first one (L1) requires a 5 V power supply capable of reaching at least 3 A.

The second one (L2) requires a 5 V power supply that is limited to 2 A.

The pretty obvious conflict is that no power supply meets both requirements at once, so I need to use a power supply that can supply both loads at max. load and protect L2 so that it isn't accidentally overloaded.

How can I do this? My first (rather uninformed) thought was to use a voltage divider, but after asking another question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698522/how-to-choose-the-proper-value-of-resistors-for-current-dividers) I noticed that that is probably not going to work.

I've searched some more around and I haven't been able to find anything that could work. I've thought of using a current limiter, but all I have found is about limiting the current to the whole circuit, and I am unsure of how it would behave in a parallel circuit

Here's a diagram of how the project more or less looks:

[image: diagram]

I've used resistors to represent the loads, but I do not know the resistance of each load (they might as well vary since they are a microcontroller and a screen). I need to somehow ensure that I can provide at least 3 A to L1, while ensuring that L2 never receives over 2 A.

How can I go about this?

I have thought about powering the screen from the microcontroller itself (so technically in series?) but I'm not sure that the microcontroller can provide enough current or at a close enough voltage to 5 V through its IO pins to power the screen, so I don't know. I don't want to risk anything breaking because the components are expensive so I'd rather figure things out in theory before attempting anything with the lab power supply.

In detail, L1 is a [Geekworm X635](https://wiki.geekworm.com/X635) board with a Raspberry Pi CM4 and an NVMe SSD, and L2 is just a generic LCD screen

Comment: Why does the LCD screen need a power supply that is limited to 2 A? Have you got specs for the screen? And no, do not try to use an IO pin as a power supply for the screen.

Comment: Where does the 2A limit requirement come from? Most 5V devices work fine without such a limit.

Comment: @ocrdu I do not know why. It's just what the product specifies, and since it cost me a fair bit I don't want to risk breaking it. The screen is one I found on amazon, so I don't trust the description much anyways, but it's all I have (https://www.amazon.com/HMTECH-Raspberry-Touchscreen-1024x600-Portable/dp/B0987468N2/)

Comment: All I see is *Power Dissipation 5V\*2A*, that does not imply the power supply needs to be limited to 2 A, just that the power supply needs to be able to deliver 2 A at 5 V; no limiting required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to have a power supply that can supply enough current for both devices operating at their max current consumption state. L1 requires at least 3A. L2 draws, at most, 2A. Take the sum of these loads: 3A + 2A = 5A. You will need a power supply that can provide 5A @ 5V. A good engineer will go with something higher than 5A in a professional setting where reliability matters.

In other words, The loads are only going to draw as much current as the need - not how much current the power supply can force down there proverbial throats. The max and min current specs are device specs. Not power supply specs.

Comment: Do I not need to worry about overcurrent protection then?

Comment: @CiroGarcía Short answer is no. You will not need to worry about overcurrent protection. But you could always include a appropriate fuse in series with each of the branches.